# How to set float on Meteor login buttons

Tags: javascript, css, meteor

I have this navbar inside my layoutTemplate

```
<template name='layoutTemplate'>
    <div class="container-fluid layout_container">
        <div class="navbar layout_navbar">
            <h3 class='layout_header'>maglens</h3>
            <a class='button-text btn' id='home_button' href="{{pathFor 'home'}}">HOME</a>
            {{> loginButtons}}
            <a class='button-text btn' id='about_button' href="{{pathFor 'about'}}">ABOUT</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{> yield}}
</template>
```

And Ive inspected the html class of the `{{> loginButtons}}` but when I try to set float (even with `!important`), nothing happens.  I can use padding/margin to get to the place I need, but that messes with the responsiveness of the website.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the [unstyled](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-ui-unstyled) version?

It will be easier to modify.

EDIT: if you want to dig into modifying unstyled, check out the [repo](https://github.com/Charuru/accounts-ui-unstyled). There are two files in particular you want to see: accounts-ui.js & login_buttons.html (which are events and markup, respectively).

Personally, I've been writing my own login forms, because Accounts is actually part of the core API, which suit whatever front-end framework I'm using.

You can easily roll out your own by consulting the docs and checking the section titled Accounts. Here some of my code:

```
//create a moderator for a blank app
Meteor.startup(function () {

  if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {

    var andy = {
      email: 'andy@admin.ca',
      password: 'samplepw',
      profile: {
        role: "moderator",
        name: "Andy"
      }
    }
...
Accounts.createUser(andy);
```

That's how you can tap into Accounts to do some magic.

```
// an entire template login modal (semantic ui)

<template name="login">
  {{#if currentUser}}

  <a href="#" class="item">{{currentUserEmail}}</a>

  <a data-logout class="item">
    Logout
  </a>

  {{else}}

  <a data-open-login-modal class="borderless item">  Login
  </a>

  <div id="loginModal" class="ui modal">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
      Sign in
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <form id="loginForm" class="ui form">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="text">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div style="background-color: #F7F7F7" class="ui green bottom attached segment">
      <div data-register class="ui blue button">Register</div>
      <div data-login class="ui green button float-right">Login</div>
      <div data-forgot-password class="ui yellow button float-right">Forgot password?</div>
    </div>  
  </div> 

  <div id="registerModal" class="ui modal">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
      Register a New Account
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <form id="registerForm" class="ui form">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="text">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input name="confirm" type="password">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #F7F7F7" class="ui green bottom attached segment">
      <div data-create-account class="ui green button float-right">Create Account</div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Above is the markup...here's the events:

```
Template.login.events({
  'click [data-open-login-modal]': function(e, tpl){

    var login = $('#loginModal').modal('toggle');
    var registeration = $('#registerModal');

    login.on('click', '[data-login]', function(){
      var email = $('#loginForm > [name="email"]').val();
      var password = $('#loginForm > [name="password"]').val();

      // this.keypress(function(event){
      //   console.log(event); 
      //   if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      //     loginUser();
      //   }
      // });

    if (email.length > 0 && password.length > 0) {
      Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(e){
        if(e) {
          console.log(e) 
        } else {
          console.log('user should be getting logged in...' + email); 
        }
        $('#loginModal').modal('toggle');
      })
    }

    });

    login.on('click', '[data-register]', function(){
      registeration.modal('toggle').on('click', '[data-create-account]', function(tpl){
        var email = $('#registerForm > [name="email"]').val();
        var password = $('#registerForm > [name="password"]').val();
        var confirmation = $('#registerForm > [name="confirm"]').val();

        // check that email/password aren't empty and that
        // email/confirmation are the same

        if (email.length > 0 && password.length > 0 && password === confirmation) {
          var user = {
            "email": email,
            "password": password,
            "profile": {
              'roles': ['basic'],
              'rep': 1
            }
          };

          Meteor.call('registerUser', user, function(err, res){
            if (!err) {
              Meteor.loginWithPassword(res.email, res.password, function(){
                registeration.modal('toggle');
              })  
            } else {
              console.log(err); 
            }
          })

        } else {
          console.log('Fields are missing'); 
        }

      });
    });

    login.on('click', '[data-forgot-password]', function(){
      console.log('clicked forgot-password'); 
    });         
},
'click [data-logout]': function() {
  Meteor.logout(function(){
    console.log('logged out'); 
  })
}

});

Template.login.onRendered = function() {
  $('#authenticateForm').modal();
  $('#registerForm').modal();
}
```

It's not quite done, which you can see there's no logic for forgot-password, but register/login is completely functional.

Really, you're just getting `.val()` from a form, and then passing data to Accounts, at the simplest level.

Comment: This answer would benefit of a small example.

Comment: @ilrein ... where can I make changes to dropdown vs pop up, etc ?  do i create a service.js file and user a Service configuration?